# split string in uppercase and camel case halves

Tags: regex, string, split

I have a set of strings in the form `"UPPERCASE STRING Normal string"`. The uppercase part is made of different number of words (from 1 to 3), the second part sometime is absent. I am trying to separate those strings in two `(es "UPPERCASE STRING" "Normal string")` but I am not a RegEx guru: who can help?

Comment: Could you please provide what languages (natural and programming ones) you are working with? What is the regex flavor you are using?

Comment: sure, natural languages are english and italian. I am working with lib_ mysqludf_preg in MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
^([A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)+) (.*?)$
```

You'll have the uppercase words in group 1 and the rest in group 2

If you want to deal with any language:

```
^(\p{Lu}+(?: \p{Lu}+)+) (.*?)$
```

Comment: And what about "ИМЯ ФАМИЛИЯ отчество конец строки"?

Comment: @stribizhev: I'm too lazy to find the correspondance to character class :(

Comment: No cyrillic or javascript! My answer was too generic perhaps but @Toto has been of great help, thank you (thank you stribizhev too for the punctualizations)

Comment: It is true that many regex flavors support `\p{UNICODE_CATEGORY}` patterns, I am just reluctant to answer questions that are not totally clear to me. I often get downvoted for such answers, and it made me more careful with such quick answers.